# In Cerberus can you use 'valueschema' with a type of 'dict'?

Tags: python, cerberus

So I'm using Cerberus for schema validation, but I'm running into a particular with validating a subdictionary of a dictionary whose key is unknown.

So say I have the following document:

```
dict = {
   'things': {
       '0463': {
           'foo': 'blah',
           'bar': 'bleep'
        },
        '0464': {
           'foo': 'x',
           'bar': 'y'
        },
        'another_random_id': {
           'foo': 'blah',
           'bar': 'bleep'
        }
}
```

So i want to validate that the subdictionaries have a specific structure (`foo` and `bar` as keys), but I can't figure out a way to validate this without knowing the keys ahead of time (which in my case are random id's. I figured this was a good use of valueschema but i can't seem to get valueschema to work with something of type 'dict'. I tried to set the following schema in cerberus:

```
schema = {
    'things': {
        'type': 'dict',
        'valueschema': {
             'type': 'dict',
             'foo': {'type': 'string'},
             'bar': {'type': 'string'}
         }
     }
}
```

Am i defining my schema incorrectly or is this not possible with the current implementation of `valueschema`. I saw some tests in the repository that used `valueschema`, but they were only testing where the type of `valueschema` was an int or a string.

Comment: If this is still an issue, please open a bug report that includes a description of the behaviour that you encountered and that you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I figured out that cerberus will handle `valueschema` if it's of type `dict` if I put a `schema` field after the `valueschema` key. So my structure should be:

```
schema = {
    'things': {
        'type': 'dict',
        'valueschema': {
             'type': 'dict',
             'schema':{
                 'foo': {'type': 'string'},
                 'bar': {'type': 'string'}
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Now there's still some weirdness because it doesn't seem like `valueschema` was designed with the expectation that it would validate a value of type `dict`. For example when I extend from the validator, I had to override the `validate_valueschema` method so that the `required` validation acts the same as it would for a regular schema, because when it calls `validate` on the schema it doesn't pass in the `update` parameter. So my overridden `validate_valueschema` looks like this:

```
def _validate_valueschema(self, schema, field, value):
    if isinstance(value, Mapping):
        for key, document in value.items():
            validator = self._Validator__get_child_validator()
            validator.validate(
                {key: document}, {key: schema}, 
                context=self.document, update=self.update)
            if len(validator.errors):
                self._error(field, validator.errors)
```

The `update=self.update` is all I added.

Comment: Not sure if I misunderstood the documentation because on the site it uses "schema" not "valueschema"

  >>> schema = {
...   'test_field': {},
...   'a_dict': {
...     'type': 'dict',
...     'schema': {
...       'foo': {'type': 'string'},
...       'bar': {'type': 'string', 'dependencies': '^test_field'}
...     }
...   }
... }

Comment: Changed in version 0.9: renamed `keyschema` to `valueschema`. Changed in version 1.3: renamed `valueschema` to `valuesrules`. _Source: [docs.python-cerberus.org](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html?highlight=valueschema#valuesrules)_